# Why is Chrome rendering this HTML as a completely blank page? From Node.js, following The Node Beginner Book

Tags: html, node.js, google-chrome

So I've sent the following HTML to my browser using Node.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/upload" method="post">
        <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit text" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But the browser is showing a completely white blank page.  When I view source, however, I see exactly what you see above, which I just copied and pasted out of Chrome's "view source" utility.  Why is Chrome rendering that HTML as a blank page?  I have a screenshot below.

This is the Node.js code I am using to send the HTML to the browser:

```
function start(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
    var body = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n'+
               '<html>\n'+
               '<head>\n'+
               '    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\n'+
               '</head>\n'+
               '<body>\n'+
               '    <form action="/upload" method="post">\n'+
               '        <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>\n'+
               '        <input type="submit" value="Submit text" />\n'+
               '    </form>\n'+
               '</body>\n'+
               '</html>\n';

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(body);
    response.end();
}
```

[image: blank page -- in spite of good HTML that Chrome can show me...]

==================================

Here is the answer included as an edit to the original posting, since this topic was closed (it is unfortunate that topics which are not answered can be closed by others than the poster). Anyway, just in case the original poster is following this, I dug into this problem since I was having the exact same issue, nobody answered his question, and I uncovered the solution:

I have just resolved this issue of copying code snippets from a Kindle book to a text/source code editor of your choice. This same topic was discussed in a posting on stackoverflow.com entitled "Why is Chrome rendering this HTML as a completely blank page? From Node.js, following The Node Beginner Book [closed]". That particular posting describes the exact same problem I was experiencing (same Kindle book, same code snippet, same code symptom!). Unfortunately, that posting was prematurely closed before any of the respondents could provide the exact answer, otherwise I would've responded to that posting.

However, I dug into this issue more deeply and discovered the root cause of the problem when copying code snippets from Kindle books: when you copy text from the Kindle app, it uses hex code 0xA0 for space characters, not 0x20. Hex code 0xA0 is extended ASCII for non-breaking whitespace. Well, this doesn't work when you are expecting to copy-and-paste HTML literal strings, as was the case in the aforementioned posting.

And so this explains the behavior in the aforementioned posting: the original poster indicated that he could get around the problem by hand-retyping all of the text. It's because the hand re-typing was using proper 0x20.

This had other symptoms which I didn't understand at first but are now explained: my text editor (Notepad++) was not correctly identifying the reserved keywords in my source code. Again, this is because the keywords were separated by 0xA0, not 0x20. The keyword parser in Notepad++ must be tokenizing off of 0x20.

Solution: after pasting text from Kindle, perform a search and replace using regular expression searching capabilities in your source code editor. Search for regular expression \xA0 and replace it with \x20 (or, depending on your editor just type in a single space bar character in the Replace field [that is how Notepad++ works]).

Comment: What do you see in the DOM inspector?

Comment: check what are the http response headers you are getting.

Comment: I added a screen shot...

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh - how do I check the http response headers?

Comment: @JonCrowell Go to "Network tab" at the Developer tools and click on the request.

Comment: @RobW Network tab shows "200 OK" status across the board.

Comment: @JonCrowell Yes.. And what about the headers?

Comment: The element inspector looks odd--the `input` has a closing element, and is nested inside the `textarea`.

Comment: @BrandonTilley Yes, nice catch!  But the HTML I have at the top of my post is copied and pasted directly from "view source" -- so now I'm wondering what Chrome does't like about it that caused it to put the `input` inside the `textarea`...

Comment: Well, I removed the `name="text"` from the `textarea` element and it began rendering a page with a text area, but no input button.  Then I put it back to the way it used to be, and it kept rendering a page with a text area and no input button. I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: @RobW I just checked the headers: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 18:58:54 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: @JonCrowell See my answer. Maybe adding `Content-Length` will fix it.

Comment: Thanks to all who commented.  I've decided that the problem had something to do with copying and pasting the code out of my Kindle app -- once I deleted white space and re-typed it things began working as expected.  I'm still not sure precisely what the issue was, however.

Comment: @JonCrowell I'm voting to close this question as "Too Localised", because what you've experienced will probably never be relevant to anyone else. Do you agree?

Comment: I don't mind if you vote to close it.  I expect other people will run into trouble when they copy and paste code examples out of their Kindle apps, but I don't see how they're going to find this discussion through normal search channels.

Answer (score 2):

I bet this is because you didn't set the content length header (`Content-Length`). I thought Node.js would do that automatically but maybe it doesn't.

This was an [issue in the past](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/google-chrome-blank-white-page-bug/) but I thought it had been fixed in chrome. Maybe you have an older version.

try:

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html", "Content-Length" : body.length });
```

And then look in the Chrome developer tools network tab and see if the header is being set.

Comment: Thanks.  I have Version 23.0.1271.64 of Chrome and Chrome tells me that it is up to date.  Believe it or not, I got it working by simply re-typing the lines in my text editor.  I originally copied and pasted the code out of a Kindle eBook and I think it might have inserted some strange and invisible characters into the text.  Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe it was a [**BOM**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (pun intended).

Comment: Hmmm, looking at that Wikipedia page was enlightening.  I noticed that I specified UTF-8 as my charset, but I'll bet that when I copied and pasted from my Kindle it didn't all come over as straightforward UTF-8.

Comment: Its probably not it. I just wanted to make a joke :)

Answer (score 2):

using the server example code from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/) and your html works fine in Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var body = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n'+
         '<html>\n'+
         '<head>\n'+
         '    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\n'+
         '</head>\n'+
         '<body>\n'+
         '    <form action="/upload" method="post">\n'+
         '        <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>\n'+
         '        <input type="submit" value="Submit text" />\n'+
         '    </form>\n'+
         '</body>\n'+
         '</html>\n';
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(body);
  res.end();
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

so as legacy said, it must be something else

Comment: This should just be a comment on legacy's answer.

Comment: yeah, you might be right. just didn't want follow the direction pointing to a different browser and changing chrome settings. the code should work as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I tested using my own node.js server, and I think an extension is changing the html. Try accessing in a different browser, and in chrome in incognito mode.

Comment: I was getting the same behavior in other browsers.  It is working now, though, after I retyped the code in my text editor.  I think my mistake was copying and pasting directly from my Kindle app on my MacBook Pro into Sublime Text 2 -- Kindle adds extra stuff to what you copy and paste, such as information about the title and author, which I deleted, but I think it also adds various other invisible characters to content that is copied.  At least that is my best guess about what is going on.